# How to perform traversal in Gremlin With Edge Label

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a somewhat a simple question but I am still trying to grasp the gremlin language and graphing databases in general. I have the following items in the graph. This is just a single path but I want to find the nodes attached to the edges with property "ABC".

This is my graph for example:

```
a = g.addV("building").property("name", "A").next()
b = g.addV("building").property("name", "B").next()
c = g.addV("building").property("name", "C").next()
d = g.addV("building").property("name", "D").next()
e = g.addV("building").property("name", "E").next()

g.addE("path").from(a).to(b).property("ident", "ABC")
g.addE("path").from(b).to(c).property("ident", "ABC")
g.addE("path").from(c).to(d).property("ident", "ABC")
g.addE("path").from(d).to(e).property("ident", "ABC")

g.addE("path").from(a).to(b).property("ident", "XYZ")
g.addE("path").from(b).to(c).property("ident", "XYZ")
g.addE("path").from(c).to(d).property("ident", "XYZ")
g.addE("path").from(d).to(e).property("ident", "XYZ")
```

What I am trying to do is find the edges with `.has("path", "ident", "ABC")`. I can do this, but
I am trying to figure out how to take that and end up showing the graph. I am trying to figure out how to get:

```
A->path->B->path->C->path->D->path->E
```

Again thanks in advance and you don't have to solve but help just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a combination of `repeat()` steps with filtering on the edge property `ident` using the `has()` step like this:

`g.V().has('building', 'name', 'A').repeat(outE('path').has('ident', 'ABC').inV()).until(outE('path').count().is(0)).path()`

Comment: This is awesome but here is another one that I have been stuck on. What if I want to start at building C? So I have been playing with that and seem not to be able to get that to work. I don't know if this is even possible.

So I would expect to get the same results as above but feed in `.has('builiding', 'name', 'C')`

Comment: Can you provide a little more clarity here.  If you were to start at C then you would not get the same path as above, as your path would always start a C not A.  You could traverse the ABC edge in both directions by changing outE() to bothE() and inV() to otherV() but in that case you would not find any additional paths that end with a count=0

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I am trying to figure a path from A to Z but if given only vertex D it would need to find the furtherest point on each side and then return that where it would be A to Z with D in the path . I will look at trying the both option and try to traverse that way.  Thank you for the pointers.